# Sharing unnamed memory on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, memory

On Windows, how to share an already allocated, unnamed piece of memory between processes ?

Context:

I want to access the same physical memory from two different processes, without one of them "knowing" about it. Basically, I want to read process A's memory from process B.

I thought about ReadProcessMemory() but, from what I've understood (and I might be wrong, and if I am please tell me), ReadProcessMemory actually copies the memory form a physical address to another, mapping then the copy to process B's virtual memory (or putting it in an already mapped area, doesn't matter).

What I would like to be able to do is to map the same physical area from the two processes. I thought about CreateFileMapping()/MapViewOfFile(), but (again, from what I've understood) you need to explicitly name the area you want to map. I don't have a name for process A's memory, all I know is process A' virtual address of that memory (from VirtualQueryEx() ). In my mind I believe this should be enough to get the job done, but i haven't found the way, yet. Any tip?

EDIT: I should make clear that i don't want to share a word or something small, rather a set of virtual pages, so offsets and similars aren't a problem.

Comment: This is now possible in the latest versions of Windows 10, by calling `VirtualAlloc2` with the `MEM_RESERVE_PLACEHOLDER` flag. This is followed by calling `MapViewOfFile3` with the `MEM_REPLACE_PLACEHOLDER`. Example code, however, is thin on the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared memory (named or unnamed) has to be created via CreateFileMapping() and then accessed via MapViewOfFile(). A structure is normally used to define offsets and types. I'm not aware of a way to share the normal memory of a process.

ReadProcessMemory() and WriteProcessMemory() are debugger like functions that read / write the memory from another process.

Comment: What worries me about ReadProcessMemory is the possible overhead. Does it really copy the specified memory like a memcpy() call would do or the OS does some hidden optimization, ideally similar to what copy-on-write on a UNIX fork would do? (I'd be able to read the other process' memory without copying it, but if i mess with the buffer it gets actually copied?)

Comment: @Shinatose - it copies the memory. It seems that Windows doesn't have a way to create a shared map for the main memory of a process. Shared memory has to be allocated using CreateFileMapping().